# Action Mailbox saying "Missing required Mailgun API key" even though key is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action-mailbox

I have Mailgun set up to forward emails to my `/rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime` endpoint.

When my endpoint receives the request, it gives the following error:

> ArgumentError (Missing required Mailgun API key. Set
> action_mailbox.mailgun_api_key in your application's encrypted
> credentials or provide the MAILGUN_INGRESS_API_KEY environment
> variable.)

However, `MAILGUN_INGRESS_API_KEY` is in fact set. When I run `ENV["MAILGUN_INGRESS_API_KEY"]` in the console, I see my API key. I even pasted in the [API key determination code from GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailbox/app/controllers/action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails_controller.rb#L80-L94) to see if there was a problem there, but the return value I got was my actual API key.

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Just checking few things to see if can rectify, as I understand you know much better than me about rails.

- Do you have setup mailgun api_key in environment configuration like for development `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
  config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
    api_key: ENV['MAILGUN_INGRESS_API_KEY'],
    domain: 'your_domain.com',
    # api_host: 'api.eu.mailgun.net'  # Uncomment this line for EU region domains
  }
```

Now let us do one test, visit (bin.mailgun.net) and get paste bin url then run `rails c`

```
mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new(ENV["MAILGUN_INGRESS_API_KEY"], "bin.mailgun.net", "aecf68de_you_got_visiting_site", ssl = false)
message_params = {  from: 'bob@sending_domain.com',
                    to: 'sally@example.com',
                    subject: 'The Ruby SDK is awesome!',
                    text: 'It is really easy to send a message!'
                  }
result = mg_client.send_message("your_sending_setup_on_mailgun_domain.com", message_params)

puts result.inspect
```

See what message came and you may get idea. There could be environment configuration issue also for development you have to setup different then for production. Also check on paste-bin does it got any hit.